# Set AntiForgeryToken for redirect to HttpGet method in C#

Tags: c#, redirect, http-post, csrf

I want to check for CSRF in my webapp using the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute. The thing is, I have a GET method that changes data, so it should actually be a POST. But aside from a submit to this action method in the corresponding form, there are multiple redirects to this method, so I can't change it to a POST method. As far as I know, the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] doesn't work for GET methods. Is there another way to validate a GET method or to redirect within the code to a POST method without using a form?

My action method looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
    // changes are made in database!!

    return View("View", model);
}
```

And this action method is being redirected to from another action method:

```
public ActionResult SomeOtherAction()
{
    return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "Controller");
}
```

I would like to change the first action to:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
    // changes are made in database!!

    return View("View", model);
}
```

and add @Html.AntiForgeryToken in the corresponding view. But then the redirect in the second action won't work anymore. Does anyone know a way out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return the someAction method...

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SomeOtherAction()
        {
            return SomeAction();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SomeAction()
        {
            return View("SomeAction");
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeOtherAction", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works to work around the redirect. But how do I set the AntiForgeryToken in SomeOtherAction() to pass to SomeAction()?

Comment: @susanvp i have update the answer. [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] also work's with GET, if the answer suits you, mark it as correct please